# How can I get round shape avatar even after I have used rounded property in Avatar element

Tags: react-native, react-native-elements

I am trying to implement a round shape avatar for my user profile screen. But I don't know why it is not appearing round.

I have checked my style sheet and also tried to put avatar element into another view tag. But its not working.

> My Profile Screen :

```
 return(

            <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.header}></View>
                <Avatar
                    style={styles.avatarContainer}
                    size={"large"}
                    rounded
                    onPress={this.takePicture}
                    activeOpacity={0.7}
                    source={{uri:User.image}}
                    showEditButton
                    avatarStyle={{borderRadius:63}}
                />

            <View style={styles.body}>
              <View style={styles.bodyContent}>
                <Text style={styles.name}>{User.name}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.info}>{User.phone}</Text>     
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.updateProfile} style={styles.buttonContainer}>
                  <Text style={{color:'#fff'}}>UPDATE</Text>  
                </TouchableOpacity>              
                {/* <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._logOut} style={styles.buttonContainer}>
                  <Text>LOGOUT</Text> 
                </TouchableOpacity> */}
              </View>
          </View>
        </View>
        )
```

> My Style Sheet:

```
  avatarContainer: {
    borderRadius: 63,
    height:130, 
    width:130,
    borderWidth: 4,
    borderColor: "white",
    marginBottom:10,
    alignSelf:'center',
    position: 'absolute',
    marginTop:130
  },
```

I want my avatar element in round shape but it comes up in square shape.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using `Avatar` from `react-native-elements`, so i took a look at its source code. here is the data you can pass to it ( i removed some parts which won't help you):

```
Avatar.propTypes = {
  containerStyle: ViewPropTypes.style,
  source: RNImage.propTypes.source,
  avatarStyle: ViewPropTypes.style,
  rounded: PropTypes.bool,
  overlayContainerStyle: ViewPropTypes.style,
  activeOpacity: PropTypes.number,
  icon: PropTypes.object,
  iconStyle: Text.propTypes.style,
  size: PropTypes.oneOfType([
    PropTypes.oneOf(['small', 'medium', 'large', 'xlarge']),
    PropTypes.number,
  ]),
  imageProps: PropTypes.object,
  ImageComponent: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.func, PropTypes.object]),
};
```

what you should do is to pass image `borderRaduis` prop.

```
imageProp: {
    borderRadius: 100
}
```

Note: if i were you i would create my own round component, its not hard at all and also you will have more control over it.